# android 2.2 can't play AAC Mono and 128x98 Video?

Tags: android, streaming

our engineer test video and audio player using streaming aac mono contents and 128x98 video content.

aac and mp4 decoder can't decoding content. and return error.

android not support low level contents?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the platform itself more than the android framework. What phone / processor / system configuration you are using.

Also mp4 is only the container. If inside is actually MPEG4-AVC video, then there are a lot of different profiles, bitrates that can affect whether your android will be able to decode correctly.

Comment: we use qualcomm 7x27 processor. I think that streaming buffer calculation code is wrong or decoder has a problem. because local play has not problem. and problem only happen very low level streaming content. 16kbit aac mono and 128x98 video.